# Coverting C script to PHP

Tags: php, c

I want to study the following script in PHP, it's actually in C, how can I convert the exactly same code to PHP?

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {
int equi(int arr[], int n) {
if (n==0) return -1; 
long long sum = 0;
int i; 
for(i=0;i<n;i++) sum+=(long long) arr[i]; 

long long sum_left = 0;    
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    long long sum_right = sum - sum_left - (long long) arr[i];
    if (sum_left == sum_right) return i;
    sum_left += (long long) arr[i];
} 
return -1; 
}
```

}

Comment: Php and C has very close syntax just remove data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take out return type for functions(unless you want to do it in php7) and remove variable types. In php function starts with keyword 'function'. Here is the possible conversion of your code. There should not syntax error but a little change in code might need to get exact functionality of C.

```
<?php 

function solution($A, $N) {
    function equi($arr, $n) {
        if ($n==0) return -1; 
        $sum = 0;
        for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) 
            $sum+=$arr[$i]; 

        $sum_left = 0;    
        for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
            $sum_right = $sum - $sum_left - $arr[$i];
            if ($sum_left == $sum_right) return $i;
            $sum_left += $arr[$i];
        } 
        return -1; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool available that will make direct conversion of C code to PHP code. You have to learn PHP and write the code. PHP and C have similar syntax. Test it by all possible test cases and make sure you are getting same result as of C code.